# Is it possible to install Visual Studio community edition onto a windows server 2016?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-server-2016

The installer simply aborts after running up the executable ('vs_community_ENU__59881795.1484281787.exe').

[image]

Is the installation possible at all? Is there any workaround to get pass the 'abort' error message?

Comment: Check the installation log

Comment: Where is the log located?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221660/where-is-the-visual-studio-2008-installation-log

Comment: Verify and update your question you have all Visual Studio requirements already installed

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks a lot for all the links and info